# Returning results from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to do a simple SELECT to return rows of data from my database. I have a valid connection from my database so I know the issue is not there. I have ensured the names of each column are correct but it just returns 0 results.

My table inside the db is called 'user' and here is the members.php file:

`<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` <- this is where the db conect file is pulled in.

```
    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT id, username, email_address FROM user";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo 
                $row["id"];
            }

        } else {
            echo "0 Members";
        }

        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Just for ref here is my DB connection (Not the most secure i am just testing):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***********";
$password = "**********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    echo "Connected successfully<br><br>";
?>
```

Comment: did it echo something??

Comment: It echos out "0 Members" If I take away the DB connection is does not echo that out

Comment: did you have any record in user table, run this query SELECT id, username, email_address FROM user in your Db directly

Comment: running that query works 'Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0000 seconds.)'

Comment: Can you show us how you made your d.b connection other wise there will be no mistake.

Comment: So you have nothing in that table apparently... it's not a bug but a feature :-)

Comment: LOL `Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0000 seconds.)'` so what do u expect from PHP to echo ???

you have no record inside that table

Comment: @user3725879 if there is no record how will you expect to echo data in you php code??

Comment: I can see there are two records in there now? Is it a problem of how I have setup my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didnt select your database

```
$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

this require another parameter which is your d.b name

```
$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db_name);
```